# Return data based on model flag for OnetoOne Nested Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a nested serializer for onetoone mapping for a model offer. But i want the nested serializer to only return data if the fllag in the model instance of nested serializer is set to true. I guess to_representation will not work here as it will receive an object instance rather than queryset.

```
Model :

class Offers(models.Model) :

    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    hospital = models.OneToOneField('hospital.Providers',to_field='hospital_id',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='hospital_offer',blank=True,null=True)
    validity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    terms =  models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Serializer :
class ProviderOffersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) : 
    class Meta :
        model = Offers
        fields = ('brand','id')

class ProviderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hospital_offer = ProviderOffersSerializer(read_only=True)
    network = NetworkSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Providers
        fields = ('hospital_id','hospital_name','hospital_offer','pincode','network')
```

Now ProviderSerializer should return data for offer only if active is True. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This code is working : 
def to_representation(self, offer):
        if offer.active :
            return ProviderOffersSerializer(offer).data
        return None
Is this right way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you gave yourself in the comments is proper in my opinion, but it can be simplified.

Instead of referencing the serializer itself, by calling the `to_representation` method from the superclass (`ModelSerializer`), you can get exactly what you want - the serializer `Offer` object.

Here is the full code example:

> serializers.py

```
class ProviderOffersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) : 
    class Meta :
        model = Offers
        fields = ('brand', 'id')

    def to_representation(self, offer):
        return super().to_representation(offer) if offer.active else None
```

You can also benefit from Python semantics here. The code is as readable as English itself - *"serialize the offer if it is active, otherwise - return nothing"*.